# Can't access modem manager gui on ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: networking, network-manager, usb-modem, modem, 3g

i have modem manager gui version 0.0.18-3 in ubuntu 16.04 LTS when access modem-manager-gui show message error like this :

```
Connection manager: Network Manager >= 0.9.0
Modem manager: Modem Manager >= 0.7.0

** (modem-manager-gui:2909): WARNING **: Modem Manager >= 0.7.0: 
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: 
Rejected send message, 2 matched rules;   
type="method_call", sender=":1.96" (uid=1000 pid=2909 comm="modem-manager-gui ") 
interface="org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.Modem.Contacts"
member="GetCount" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0"
destination=":1.2" (uid=0 pid=856 comm="/usr/sbin/ModemManager ")
Segmentation fault at address: 0x30

Stack trace:
1. /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0xc3071) [0x7f67f03a0071]
2. /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0xc3071) [0x7f67f03a0071]
3. /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(strftime_l+0x16) [0x7f67f03a20a6]
4. modem-manager-gui(mmgui_str_format_sms_time+0xe7) [0x411b87]
5. modem-manager-gui() [0x42cdb0]
6. modem-manager-gui(mmgui_main_sms_list_fill+0x306) [0x42f226]
7. modem-manager-gui() [0x438450]
8. modem-manager-gui(mmguicore_devices_open+0x149) [0x421879]
9. modem-manager-gui(mmgui_main_device_select_from_list+0x10a) [0x430d8a]
```

when i run sudo apt-cache policy modem-manager-gui network-manager

```
sudo apt-cache policy modem-manager-gui network-manager
modem-manager-gui:
  Installed: 0.0.18-3
  Candidate: 0.0.18-3
  Version table:
 *** 0.0.18-3 500
        500 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
network-manager:
  Installed: 1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.2
  Candidate: 1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.2
  Version table:
 *** 1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 500
        500 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.2.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.4 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
     1.1.93-0ubuntu4 500
        500 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Please update your question with output of `apt-cache policy modem-manager-gui network-manager`.

Comment: okay i have run your command, what next?

Comment: You have normal versions from official repository. I can't detect any problems here.

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is an old question but maybe someone like me will face the same issue. After some digging I found the answer [here](https://linuxonly.ru/forum/modem-manager-gui/32/modem-manager-gui-failing-to-start-with-dongle-on/):

> For some reason application crashes while converting SMS message timestamp. Could you, please, try to remove (or rename) directory with messages database and try to start MMGUI. Command to rename this directory:
>
> ```
> mv ~/.local/share/modem-manager-gui ~/.local/share/modem-manager-gui.old
> ```

The next step is to replug the modem and run `modem-manager-gui`.

Shout out and huge thank you to Alex the author of MMGUI!